# Display items in a listbox in a messagebox C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I am writing a windows form application that requires me to print the items of a listbox in a messagebox and well . . . here is what I have:

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object selectedItem in ListBoxCondiments.Items)
    {
        str.AppendLine(ListBoxCondiments.Items.ToString());
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Your made-to-order Burger will include:" + str, "Custom Burger!");
}
```

And as a result I am receiving a messagebox with string and instead of the items in my list
I receive System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox + . . . (until the end of the list)

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use selectedItem.ToString().

```
str.AppendLine(selectedItem.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
str.AppendLine(ListBoxCondiments.Items.ToString())
```

Into this

```
str.AppendLine(selectedItem.ToString())
```